# C++ any standard library for reading binary values from a stream

Tags: c++, iostream

I mean say I have a file that contains 4 bytes `0x2a x00 0x00 0x00`

I would like to go (assuming f is an open ifstream)

```
uint32_t x;
f >> x;
```

and have x contain 42

I know this doesn't work but it seems like such an obvious thing to do it is surprising that it isn't in the standard. For example an open flag that says ios::binaryio.

The suggested thing is usually

```
f.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&x), sizeof(x));
```

which is plain ugly and unsafe

Comment: Besides your binary value potentially being `‭704643072‬` (and not 42), how should the compiler differentiate between reading a character sequence as a number vs. reading in a binary sequence? It can't, so all the overloaded input operators would have to check if the stream was binary or text to decide. And just because a stream is opened as binary doesn't mean I want to interpret the contents as binary. I can still put text in them.

Comment: well how about (as i suggested) an open flag or two, ios::binaryio, ios::binaryio_le, ios_binary_be. binaryio would use the platforms endianness or you could force a specific one.

Comment: @TedLyngmo fixed the typo

Comment: You probably have the `hton(s/l)` and `ntoh(s/l)` functions  for 16/32 bit unsigned integers available although they are non-standard. If you want to store or send a value over a stream I suggest you use those. People are used to handling network byte order so I think that's the format to stick with.

Comment: Btw, in what way is `f.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&x), sizeof(x));` unsafe? I don't see it.

Comment: @TedLyngmo because I might have typed f.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&x), sizeof(y)), this will compile, or even f.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&x), sizeof(int)) and but x is in fact short, reinterpret_cast always says, "trust me I am a doctor"

Comment: @pm100 Ah, I get it and agree that when you have some sort of interface where the type and its size are separated - )(/& may happen. It's best to keep that kind of logic in a closely guarded place that gets code reviewed a lot if anyone wants to tamper with it. A small template like Nathan suggested could be a start.

Answer (score 2):

> is there still no library standard for reading binary values from a stream

There are two: the C API and the C++ one.

> which is plain ugly

It is always possible to wrap those calls into a more elegant interface tailored to what you need.

> and unsafe

The wrapper can also take care of that.

Comment: Its actually harder than you think to write a general purpose thing (I already tried). one that accepts an arbitrary type , works with fstream and ifstream,... So I ended up rolling my own highly specific set of functions. Maybe I should write my own std::vector too /s

Comment: @pm100 Wouldn't `template <typename Stream, typename T> auto& read(Stream& stream, T& obj) { return stream.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>&obj, sizeof(ojb)); }` be all you need?

Comment: @NathanOliver +1, I have written similar functions for a few projects.

Answer (score 0):

Not yet standard I guess...
But you can easily find one or write it yourself.
Here's an example found on [GitHub](https://github.com/NxtLvLSoftware/binary-stream/blob/master/include/BinaryStream.h)

Here's another:

```
class StreamUtility
{
public:
    StreamUtility();
    StreamUtility(const StreamUtility&) = delete;
    StreamUtility& operator=(const StreamUtility&) = delete;
    ~StreamUtility() = default;
    
    enum endianness{ eBigEndian=0, eLittleEndian };
    
    static endianness getLocalMachineByteOrder();
    endianness getStreamFormat() const {return mStreamFormat;}
    bool readBytes(std::istream& iStream, size_t iNumberOfBytesToRead, char *oV);
    bool readBytes(std::istream& iStream, size_t iNumberOfBytesToRead, std::string *oV);
    bool readChar(std::istream& iStream, size_t iNumberOfCharToRead, std::string *oV);
    bool readDouble(std::istream& iStream, double *oV);
    bool readFloat32(std::istream& iStream, float *oV);
    bool readInt8(std::istream& iStream, int8_t *oV);
    bool readInt16(std::istream& iStream, int16_t *oV);
    bool readInt32(std::istream& iStream, int32_t *oV);
    bool readInt64(std::istream& iStream, int64_t *oV);
    bool readUint8(std::istream& iStream, uint8_t *oV);
    bool readUint16(std::istream& iStream, uint16_t *oV);
    bool readUint32(std::istream& iStream, uint32_t *oV);
    bool readUint64(std::istream& iStream, uint64_t *oV);

    void setStreamFormat(endianness);

    void write(std::ostream& iStream, ByteArray);
    void write(std::ostream& iStream, int8_t);
    void write(std::ostream& iStream, int16_t);
    void write(std::ostream& iStream, int32_t);
    void write(std::ostream& iStream, int64_t);
    void write(std::ostream& iStream, uint8_t);
    void write(std::ostream& iStream, uint16_t);
    void write(std::ostream& iStream, uint32_t);
    void write(std::ostream& iStream, uint64_t);
    void write(std::ostream& iStream, float);
    void write(std::ostream& iStream, double);
    void write(std::ostream& iStream, size_t iNumberOfBytesToWrite, const char *ipData);
    void writeBytes(std::ostream& iStream, const std::string& iData);
    void writeChar(std::ostream& iStream, const std::string& iData);
    
protected:
    bool needsSwapping() const;
    void swapBytes2(void* iV);
    void swapBytes4(void* iV);
    void swapBytes8(void* iV);
    
    endianness mStreamFormat;
};
```